# Consecutive paragraph headings in the same line

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

How do I convince LaTeX to write consecutive headings of the paragraph level in the same line?

In the following minimal example, I've included the *original* definitions of `\paragraph`, `\@startsection`, and `\@xsect`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
%% from latex.ltx, unchanged
\def\@startsection#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
  \par
  \@tempskipa #4\relax
  \@afterindenttrue
  \ifdim \@tempskipa <\z@
    \@tempskipa -\@tempskipa \@afterindentfalse
  \fi
  \if@nobreak
    \everypar{}%
  \else
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace\@tempskipa
  \fi
  \@ifstar
    {\@ssect{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}%
    {\@dblarg{\@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}}}

\def\@xsect#1{%
  \@tempskipa #1\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \par \nobreak
    \vskip \@tempskipa
    \@afterheading
  \else
    \@nobreakfalse
    \global\@noskipsectrue
    \everypar{%
      \if@noskipsec
        \global\@noskipsecfalse
       {\setbox\z@\lastbox}%
        \clubpenalty\@M
        \begingroup \@svsechd \endgroup
        \unskip
        \@tempskipa #1\relax
        \hskip -\@tempskipa
      \else
        \clubpenalty \@clubpenalty
        \everypar{}%
      \fi}%
  \fi
  \ignorespaces}

%% from book.cls
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Text
\paragraph{Test 1} Text

\paragraph{Test 2}
\paragraph{Test 3} Text

\paragraph{Test 4} Text
\end{document}
```

My desired output would be something like

[image: Desired Output]

---

**Update, a few hours later**

I experimented a bit and came up with the following solution:

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
%% \@tempboxa apparently is used by the counter of \section, so we create our own box:
\newbox \@tempsecbox
\def\@startsection#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  % prevent preceeding heading from being expanded too early:
  % \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
  \par
  \@tempskipa #4\relax
  \@afterindenttrue
  \ifdim \@tempskipa <\z@
    \@tempskipa -\@tempskipa \@afterindentfalse
  \fi
  \if@nobreak
    \everypar{}%
  \else
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace\@tempskipa
  \fi
  \@ifstar
    {\@ssect{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}%
    {\@dblarg{\@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}}}
\def\@xsect#1{%
  \@tempskipa #1\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \par \nobreak
    \vskip \@tempskipa
    \@afterheading
  \else
    \@nobreakfalse
    \global\@noskipsectrue
    %% without the \leavevmode in \@startsection the preceding heading
    %% is never printed, so we store it in a temporary box which
    %% "grows" with each new consecutive heading
    \global\setbox\@tempsecbox\hbox{\ifvoid\@tempsecbox\else\unhbox\@tempsecbox\space\fi\@svsechd}%
    \everypar{%
      \if@noskipsec
        \global\@noskipsecfalse
       {\setbox\z@\lastbox}%
        \clubpenalty\@M
        %% print the fully grown heading:
        \begingroup \unhbox\@tempsecbox \endgroup
        \unskip
        \@tempskipa #1\relax
        \hskip -\@tempskipa
      \else
        \clubpenalty \@clubpenalty
        \everypar{}%
        %% Reset the \@tempsecbox
        \global\setbox\@tempsecbox\box\voidb@x
      \fi}%
  \fi
  \ignorespaces}

\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

Text
\paragraph{Test 1} Text

\paragraph{Test 2}
\paragraph{Test 3} Text

\paragraph{Test 4} Text

\end{document}
```

However, I'm not quite sure if this solution is without unforeseen consequences.  I also tried to mix inline and isolated headings of different levels, it seems to work.

Comment: Since you are not relying on automatic numbering I'd say just use `\textbf`.

Comment: Actually, I do... i just didn't want to blow up the MWE even more. Besides, I need LaTeX's sectioning mechanism for the ToC etc.

Comment: I kind of suspected that `:-)` but alas without an explanation of what your are _actually_ trying to achieve it's anybody's guess... Side question, out of curiosity: Why?!

Comment: As is stated in the first line of the OP: If a `\paragraph` follows another `\paragraph` (or `\subparagraph` follows `\paragraph`, etc.) without any text inbetween, the publisher wants both (or **all** inline-) headings to appear in the same line right next to each other, as in the picture (which i actually faked with textbf ;) ). And it should be procedural; no faking with `\textbf`, `\addcontentsline`, etc.

Comment: @Lupino You should not have two paragraph headings with nothing between them. It makes no sense to me to have a textually empty paragraph body..

Comment: @PeterWilson I'm neither the author nor the publisher of those constructions and yet they occur so i need to deal with them as a typesetter or layout programmer, respectively.

Apart from that; both `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` (and, according to the publisher, everything below) are to be typeset as inline headings and they may very well appear without content inbetween; just like `\section` and `\subsection`.

Comment: @Lupino Thank you for the explanation.  However I understand `\section{Section} \subsection{Subsection}`  but  `\section{Section} \section{Another section}` just seems wrong in a final publication. Similarly I can cope with `\paragraph{Paragraph} \subparagraph{Subparagraph}` but not `\paragraph{Paragraph} \paragraph{Another paragraph}`